# How does android choose the right layout/drawable for the correct screen resolution?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, pixel

I that When starting an android application, android makes a good "guess" as to which layout/drawable to use depending on the screen size. However, I was wondering where it chooses this from? I ask this because I have quite a few layouts which don't all work. I read on the android website that you can make a folder called layout-xhdpi, layout-ldpi... etc. But does android automatically look for layout-xhdpi or layout-ldpi or do I need to specify that anywhere?

Same goes for drawables. When creating a new application in Eclispe it makes automatically drawables folders for you but does this necessarily mean it looks for those.

Conclusion: 
Where does android look for alternative screen sizes and how/where can I change that?

Comment: `layout-sdpi`? where did you take this info out? Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: There are also variants to specify the orientation: `-land` and `-port`. If your UI is well engineered, you normally won't need the resolution variants. But you may need the orientation ones.

Comment: Im sure once i know how/where android choses layouts i can figure out the next step, orientation.

Comment: It uses the dpi and/or the screen size info. You see, a phone with an hdpi resolution may probably have a different size from a tablet with an hdpi resolution.

Comment: I know that yes, but im talking in general when an activity starts. How do I specify that if the screen has a low screen size (for example) it goes to layout-low.

Comment: Make an xml layout specific for the ldpi resolution and put it in layout-ldpi, with the same name of the normal layout. As simple as that.

Comment: But don't i have to write down the configuration qualifiers somewhere ? every time I view it in graphical mode in xhdpi it opens the layout-small.

Comment: The graphical editor... do you choose the right avd device? One set for xhdpi resolution?

Comment: Yes I did. I chose google's galaxy nexys and it keeps on chosing my small layout folder although i specified it with smal..

Comment: @Phantômaxx, Maybe [from here](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Create following layout folder

res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```